# C++ Issues to build a syntax tree using a stack

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax, tree, grammar

I'm having issues trying to build up an AST/Syntax Tree to use with simple math like (1+1) or things like (1+1>=2)

Basically I have an input string like this:

```
1 + 1 * 2
```

So I parse the input and add them on a stack of *Expression** class type

The stack would look like this:

```
1
+
1
*
2
```

Then I call a "parseTree" function to build the tree and it's nodes:

```
void BehaviourDatabase::parseStack()
{
    while (stack.size() > 1) // Stacks must only have 1 root node
    {
        Expression* top = stack.front();
        stack.pop_front();
        switch (top->getExpressionType())
        {
        case EXPRESSION_NUMBER:
            stack.push_back(top);
            break;
        case EXPRESSION_OPERATOR:
            Expression* ev1 = stack.front();
            stack.pop_front();

            Expression* ev2 = stack.front();
            stack.pop_front();

            top->setLeftNode(ev1);
            top->setRightNode(ev2);

            stack.push_back(top);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Finished building the expression stack" << std::endl;
}
```

Since the front object on the stack is **1** it will be added to the back, leaving me with an operator **+**, so I proceed and pop the next 2 expressions which would be **1 & *** - what should I do here to include parse the next operations and such to build the tree?

Basically the tree should look like this am I right?

```
       *
     +   2
   1   1
```

Comment: is it normal that you don't manage priorities (e.g your tree represents (1 + 1)* 2  and not 1+ (1*2) )  ?  Why do you use a stack to replicate your input and not convert to postfix, which would make tree construction easier ?

Comment: I'm not going to use parenthesis I just guessed the tree that should be created. Even if my stack is *+123 for: ***1 + 2 * 3*** It when using operator precedence, how should I build the root node and its childs to later evaluate?

Comment: Read about [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). This is not exactly what you trying to do but I believe that it requires similar transformations of formulas.

Comment: @Raúl Sanpedro, I think @Christophe is saying that the tree you presented at the end is backwards, it represents `(1 + 1)*2`, and not `1 + 1*2` like you'd want with normal order of operations (oop). He's just using the parentheses to emphasize oop.

Comment: Oh that's right. @Christophe I've been googling and what about if I use the following stack mode for 1 + 1 * 2 -> *+112 ? Still no idea how to build the tree.

Comment: @NO_NAME Ok, I have been messing up with that, so my stack for 1 + 1 * 2 is as follows: *+112. I've built this code and I can finally stack nodes together and only get 1 single expression as the root node http://pastebin.com/PXDzBea7 but I wonder, is it okay that the main node is a + and not the * operator?

Comment: Yes, according to priority rules, the main node is + .  No doubt about this !